# Unfair assessment of someone's intentions?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm assuming someone may have dishonourable intentions. But I want to say that I may be mistaken and they may not have dishonourable intentions. How do I express that?

Is there a word or phrase which would fit "I may be unfairly _______ but..." without being colloquial? (For example, *[dissing them](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dis)* means what I want, but it's almost slang.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited for the site requirements for such requests: please adjust if necessary. Of course, you could just say "I may be mistaken" as you do in your question.

Comment: "unfairly malign" is very common (it's an example in Merriam-Webster) but [malign](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malign) means to speak badly of someone, not to entertain bad thoughts. But [diss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diss) also means to criticize or treat with contempt, not to form a negative judgment, so are you wanting a word for assessing someone, or doing something else with that assessment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to ask for an *unfair assessment* or *unfairly assessing intentions*, but the example asks for *assessing* or *criticizing*. For *unfairly assessing* I suggest:

> I may be **misjudging** him, but ...

**misjudge**

> *transitive verb*
>
> To have an unjust opinion of [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misjudge)

> If you say that someone has **misjudged** a person or situation, you mean
> that they have **formed an incorrect idea or opinion** about them, and
> often that they have made a wrong decision as a result of this.
>
> *Perhaps I had **misjudged** him, and he was not so predictable after all.*  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/misjudge)

Comment: This is the first word that came to my mind. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "I may be unfairly **judging** them". Link to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/judge?q=Judge), see definition marked C2.